# Unity: Can different materials use the same shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, shader

My memoryprofiler shows me that i have 2 of the exact same shaders created in memory but these are used by different materials located in different asset bundles. Is it possible for me to have these materials share the same shader?

Shader1:
[image]

Shader2:
[image]

They have the exact same name and references so I'm just assuming that they're actually duplicates.